# spacy model in cloud function not working

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, spacy

my requirements.txt

```
spacy
```

my cloud function code:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

the error:

> Function failed on loading user code. Error message: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your requirements.txt should look like this. The https link will directly download the spacy model and install it when you install the dependencies from requirements.txt. The spaCy models are valid python packages. Check this [link](https://spacy.io/usage/models#models-download) for more details.

```
spacy
https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the spaCy English model. Follow the instructions at: https://spacy.io/usage/models#quickstart

Comment: pip install is not available in google cloud functions